# Android: Setup multiple deployment dependencies (*.apk) in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, deployment, project, apk

I have an Android test project that depends on several remote services. Now I want be able to install all dependent remote services at once, together with my test project and the Android project under test, like project dependencies in Visual Studio when running DLL's.

I know there is an <instrumentation> tag in AndroidManifest file, informing eclipse to install my project under test first. Are there any other AndroidManifest tags, or deployment settings in Eclipse to install my remote service projects too?

Thank you!

Comment: I think you are looking for `Right Click on your Project > Properties > Java Build path > Projects > Add` here you can add any dependent libraries.

Comment: @MMohsinNaeem Yes thank you, simply the correct answer. This works for any Android project, too. Pls. make it an real answer so I can upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for `Right Click on your Project > Properties > Java Build path > Projects > Add`

here you can add any dependent libraries.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having a problem with multiple manifest and which one or ones to use. I think you can do something like an import only in the androidmanifest.xml like this
    android:id="@+/myotherproject/id/myOtherandroidManifest:id

I haven't tried it yet but it would make scene to have one manifest as a "master" androidmanifest.xml and import sniplets from that into child projects. I got the idea from this see step 4 http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/11/android-database-content-provider.html

granted he is working on one project but he is importing xml sniplets into other xml files. I know I only answered part of your question but I hope it helps.